ng version fails with error "Cannot find module ./package.json"
I tried to install Angular CLI for learning Angular on Node 23 with npm install -g @angular/cli . The install seemed successful but post install while trying to run the ng version command I receive the following error.
An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module './package.json'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\sudha\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\src\noop.js
See "C:\Users\sudha\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-C0Y4aA\angular-errors.log" for further details.

Upon checking the files, I see that noop.js doesn't exist and in the log file mentioned above I see
[error] Error: Cannot find module './package.json'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\sudha\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\src\noop.js
    at Function._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1259:15)
    at Function._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1085:27)
    at TracingChannel.traceSync (node:diagnostics_channel:315:14)
    at wrapModuleLoad (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:218:24)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1350:12)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:138:16)
    at VersionCommandModule.run (C:\Users\sudha\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\src\commands\version\cli.js:46:28)
    at VersionCommandModule.handler (C:\Users\sudha\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\src\command-builder\command-module.js:154:39)

Could you please suggest a way to resolve this issue?

Node 23 is not supported by Angular. Try Node 22 instead. https://angular.dev/reference/versions

Thank you, that helps. I didn't know that only LTS was supported

Did downgrading to Node 23 solve your issue? If yes, I will add an answer. However on my system, I could not reproduce this issue.

Yes, but now I've run into a different issue. The Angular CLI version is 19.0.2 but ng version reports Angular v16.2.12. How do I make it use version 19 like the CLI?

Angular only supports LTS versions of Node, see the docs.
Try downgrading to Node v22.
As a rule of thumb, you should only use even-numbered (18, 20, 22, ...) Node major versions.
Odd-numbered (19, 21, 23, ...) Node major versions never enter LTS and won't be supported by Angular.
For more information, see the Node.js Releases docs.
